# A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run

Tags: windows-10, dll

I've been trying to install nodejs but it always errors. I googled and searched for all the potential ways and I also clean the system with Ccleaner and deleted the temp file and tried to install but it didn't work.

I keep getting this error
"There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

I tried to change the permissions so that everyone has full access but it didn't work either, even after logging out and then retrying after logging in.

Can someone please help me with this?

[**EDIT**]

I searched through the Temp folder and found this error log.
`Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action ConfigureEventManifestUnregister, entry: ConfigureEventManifestUnregister, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI3A1F.tmp 
=== Logging stopped: 09/06/2017  12:30:29 ===`

I hope that helps clear things.

[**Another attempt to install via chocolatey**]
This is my cli output

```
C:\Windows\System32>choco install nodejs.install
Installing the following packages:
nodejs.install
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

nodejs.install v8.1.0 [Approved]
nodejs.install package files install completed. Performing other 
installation steps.
The package nodejs.install wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): Y

Installing 64 bit version
Installing nodejs.install...
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i 
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\tools\node-v8.1.0-x64.msi" 
/quiet ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. See log for possible 
error messages.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
The install of nodejs.install was NOT successful.
Error while running 
'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
- nodejs.install (exited 1603) - Error while running 
'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

This is the log that chocolatey touched.

https://pastebin.com/UdS5vUah

Answer (score 2):

- Update Windows
- Install latest Windows Installer for your Windows version
- Update VisualARQ
- Install the 32 and 64-bit versions of VC++ Redistributable
- Clean your Appdata\Local\Temp and make sure you have correct access there

Then, run installer as admin (open cmd in admin mode and run msiexec /i PackName.msi) and if it still fails, check InstallLog.txt for details on the exact .dll that causes the error.

Comment: My windows is uptodate as of now, but How do I install the latest windows installer and update visual ARQ?

Comment: This is what I get when I try to clear the temp file 
http://prntscr.com/fhp6b4

Comment: Everyone has all the permissions as well http://prntscr.com/fhp7fd

Comment: If you are getting error while clearing TEMP means its being used. You have stop or close the program which is running or stop the services. Otherwise restart the system. Try to Clear TEMP.
Did you try that same Nodejs installer setup in other system. Is it working Fine? Which OS are you using.

Comment: @TechieGossip I tried to restart the system as well, I am using Windows 10, and I tried to do this with multiple node installers. Even version 8. Doesn't work. I tried to install via chocolatey and yarn, doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to install 64 bit. Download this [link](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.0/node-v6.11.0-x64.msi). Install it in Default Path  `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: I would refer you follow this for installation using GIT [Click here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-windows-10-tutorial/)

Comment: For the Temp problem, just open a cmd with admin rights and run: del "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*" /s /f /q /a

Comment: Ahhh nope didn't work :(

Comment: Looks like the site removed a "\". There's a "\" between Temp and star.star . Alternately, just use CD command to navigate to the TEMP and use del star.star /s /f /q /a from within it. (looks like some stars are removed too).

Comment: Here's more clear (screenshot): https://ibb.co/mXgy7a

Comment: @Overmind Clearing the Temp doesn't fix the problem

Comment: At least you're junk-free now.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will pull an Issue in nodejs's github repo? @Overmind